# How to cut a file without using another file?

Tags: c++, logging, stl, fstream

Is it possible to delete part of a file (let's say from the beginning to its half), without having to use another file?

Thank's!

Comment: Do you accept using RAM? I could read 0.5 of hole file in memory, delete it, and write 0.5 of the data I have read again.

Comment: I assume that's what OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Short answer: No, (at least most) file systems don't support that. About all you can do is create a copy (in the same or a different file) that leaves out the parts you don't want.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: if you write it in an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that no, most file systems don't attempt to support operations like that.

That leaves you with two choices. The obvious one is to create a copy of the data, leaving out the parts you don't want. You can do this either in-place (i.e., moving the data around in the same file) or by using an auxiliary file, typically copying the data to the new file, then doing something like renaming the new file to the old name.

The other major choice is to simply re-structure your file and data so you don't have to get rid of the old data at all. For example, if you want to keep the most recent N amount of data from a process, you might structure (most of) the file as a circular buffer, with a couple of "pointers" at the beginning tell you the head and tail points, so you know where to read data from/write data to. With a structure like this, you don't erase or remove the old data, you just overwrite it as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, but still you'll have to rewrite most of the file.

The rough idea is as follows:

```
open the file
beg = find the start of the fragment to be removed
len = length of the fragment to be removed
blocksize = 4096 -- example block size, may be any
datamoved = 0
do {
  fseek(pos +len +datamoved);
  if( endoffile ) return; -- finished!
  actualread = fread(buffer, blocksize)
  fseek(pos + datamoved)
  fwrite(buffer, actualread)
  datamoved += actualread
}
```

and the last step after the loop is to 'truncate' the file to the pos+datamoved size. if the underlying filesystem does not handle 'truncatefile' operation, then you have to rewrite.. but most of filesystems and libraries do support that.

Comment: FYI: on traditional HDD or Floppys or ZIP drives etc deleting a file fragment this way may be much slower than rewriting the file to a new file, because the seek-back to write may cause the drive's head to, well, seek :) May, but does not have to. Also, if you can bind your code to the specific filesystem, you may find some low-level operations that could actually insert/reorder/remove a BLOCK/INODE from the middle of the file - then you just have to move tiny amount of data, but that's quite complex thing to perform..

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough memory, read its contents fully to the memory, copy it back to the front of the file, and truncate the file.

If you do not have enough memory, copy in blocks, and only when you are done truncate the file.

Comment: But the file maybe too large to copy in memory, even with blocking which will take long time

Comment: When reading in blocks memory is not an issue. Problem with time is not memory but I/O - the larger file the longer process.